# Getting number used thread with ThreadPool

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, compact-framework

Anyone knows how one can know how many threads are being executed in an ThreadPool,using c# in .net compact framework?

I need to know this, so i can present the differences between letting .Net manage threads and being us to create,start, stop threads.

The operations that we do on those thread are frequent but very fast (simple math calculations and some webservice data acquisition using gprs), so i think that an threadPool would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't this info in CF, GetAvailableThreads isn't supported.  Yes, frequent and fast is best done with the ThreadPool instead of trying to manage it yourself.

Comment: But there is not even an hack, or an custom made thread library avaiable for that?

Comment: Well, counting running threads isn't hard if you use Interlocked.Increment at the start, Decrement at the end of the thread method.

Answer (score 1):

The default could vary but you can use the snippet below to get the numbers:

```
int min = 0, max = 0;
int min1 = 0, max1 = 0;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out max, out max1);
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out min, out min1);

Console.WriteLine( ...
```

Comment: Just a little problem with that... I'm using .net compact framework that does not have the GetMinThreads function. It only have the getMaxThreads, the QueueUserWorkItem, SetMaxThreads